# Change with properties and ivars after ARC migration

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have used the "Convert to Objective C ARC" option in Xcode 4.3 to convert a project started in Xcode 4.0 to use ARC. After fixing errors that the tool found, I went trough the process where the migration tool has removed all the release messages as well as retain attributes in my properties declarations. So now I have all of my properties having only *(nonatomic)* attribute. From reading the documentation I still don't have a clear answer on what to do.

So my question is: *In case you omit the keyword regarding the setter semantics (strong, weak, retain, assign) in the property declaration, what is the default attribute on properties when using ARC?*

I found in the documentation that the default property attribute is **assign**. However, they also say that now the default attribute for **ivars**, in case you omit it, is **strong**.

To better explain my question, here is an example. I header file we have the declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic) MyClass *objectToUse;
```

and in our implementation we just have

```
@synthesize objectToUse;
```

If we then write inside some method:

```
self.objectToUse = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

have we created an strong (retain) or weak (assign) reference? If we instead write

```
objectToUse = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

by using the ivar have we changed the situation regarding the object retention policy? It seems to me that now with ARC, the best practice of using the properties for memory management is not the same practice anymore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've opened an Technical Support Incident. The engineer verified that **the default was changed from "assign" to "strong"**. The reason is exactly the inconsistency you described. Now ivars and @properties have the same default.

He said both the documentation (and warnings some people are getting) are wrong and will be fixed. (The conversion tool is correct.) Until that is done, I would **avoid the implicit default** altogether. Always explicitly specify "strong", "weak", or "assign".

Edit: The [clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ownership.spelling.property) now officially documents this change.

Answer (score 7):

The default relationship type is still `assign`, i.e. a weak ref. In addition, in ARC mode the compiler will generate an error when `@synthesize`ing accessors unless you explicitly specify a relationship type.

The difference between assigning to `self.objectToUse` and `objectToUse` is that the second form will always use ARC to `retain` or `assign`, while the first form will use `copy` if you specified a `copy` relationship.

Comment: Given that the ARC migration removed the `retain` attribute from his property declarations, is it possible that the default has changed to `strong` as of Xcode 4.3? I don't have a computer to test it right now, but it wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: That's actually what confuses me, as all `retain` attributes are being removed by ARC that leaves all the properties having `assign` (by default) which means that after ARC migration you have to go trough all of your properties declarations and add the `strong` attribute in order to have the same behaviour. It's interesting that the delegates with `assign` attribute are changed to `unsafe_unretained`, which is fine, but is it possible that the `retain` is not changed to `strong` automatically?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the migrator to me. I seem to recall my projects `retain` attributes getting converted to `strong` in XCode 4.2

Comment: Indeed. `strong` remains `strong` after conversion, but `retain` is removed. Definitely sounds like a bug.

Comment: The question is answered, so I'll just put the **note here** that the confusion was caused by the possible bug which is seen as _Xcode 4.3  not putting the `strong` attribute on the properties which had the `retain` attribute prior to ARC migration, but just removing the `retain` attribute and leaving those properties having the default value of `assign` instead_, so you have to check the properties manually after migration. This occurred on 4.0 to 4.3 project migration.

Comment: Have you filed a bug using the form at https://bugreport.apple.com/ (otherwise, please do)?

Comment: Tried with **Xcode 4.3.1**, the same thing happens. Just filed a bug to apple.

Comment: Heh got an answer from Apple that my bug report is a duplicate. As  they are aware of it already it's up to their bugfix-priority-list-makers. In the meantime, I'll be thinking about a way round for this.

Comment: The bug is not in the conversion. The interpretation actually changed. (See my answer.)